# Regex for excluding URL

Tags: regex

I working with an email company that has a feature where they spider your site in order to provide custom content. I have the ability to have the spider ignore urls based on the regex patterns I provide.

For this system a pattern starts and ends with a "/".

What I'm trying to do is ignore http://www.website.com/2011/10 BUT allow http://www.website.com/2011/10/title-of-page.html

I would have thought the pattern below would work since it does not have a trailing slash but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
/http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches a *part* of the URL, so you need to tell it not to allow a slash to follow it:

```
/http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9][0-9](?!\/)/
```

If you want to also avoid other partial matches like in `http://www.website.com/2011/100`, then an additional [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) might help:

```
/http:\/\/www\.website\.com\/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9][0-9]\b(?!\/)/
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the regexp engine but you can probably either use $ (if the URL is tokenised beforehand) or a  match for whitespace and delimiters